# Can I use WP-CLI from a remote computer?

Tags: wp-cli, ssh

Does WP-CLI need to be used and installed on my server which has WordPress installed, and as such, I would need to `ssh` into that server in order to use it?

Comment: the answer is yes

Comment: @MarkKaplun is that the typical installation, or an a-typical installation?

Comment: no idea what is typical, It basically depend on under which user you install it, what permission it has, and can you login with thaat user via ssh